# SQL, two foreign keys referencing the same primary key of another table

Tags: sql, key, relationship

I have two tables:

```
Person(personID, name, phone, email);
Relation(child_personID, parent_playerID);
```

The relationship table helps identify children and their parent but to do this the personID from the person table has to be referenced twice as foreign. How exactly would I go about doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two foreign keys referencing the same primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284428/two-foreign-keys-referencing-the-same-primary-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could look something like this.

```
create table Person
(
  personID int primary key,
  name varchar(50),
  phone varchar(50),
  email varchar(50)
)

create table Relation
(
  child_personID int references Person(personID),
  parent_playerID int references Person(personID),
  primary key (child_personID, parent_playerID)
)
```

Comment: So will this return records from the relation table, no matter which column the match is on?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. This is the table structure with foreign key constraints that makes sure you don't add rows to `relation` table that does not have a related row in `Person`. To return rows you need a query and what rows that query returns depends on how you write your query.