# Two foreign keys referencing the same primary key

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, normalization, rdbms

Is this okay to have two foreign keys in one table referencing one primary key of other table?

EmployeeID is a primary key in the employee table and appearing as a foreign key twice in the timesheet table.

There will be few admin users filling up timsheets on the behalf of other employees.

In the timsheet table field 'TimsheetFor' will have employeeID of that person who has worked on projects and field 'EnteredBy' or 'FilledBy' will have employeeid of that person who has filled up this timesheet.

Which of the following option is correct?

***NOTE: Tables are showing only those fields which are related to this question.***

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is okay to have two fk to the same pk in one table.

Comment: Yes - **of course!** Why do you ask? What's the issue/problem you're seeing?

Comment: I wanted to asked the same question. I'm glad that I'm a apart of this great site! Thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 28):

I would go with **option 1**.  It is perfectly fine to have two foreign key columns referencing the same primary key column in a different table since each foreign key value will reference a different record in the related table.

I'm sure **option 2** would work, but you would essentially have a 1-to-1 relationship between `TIMESHEET_TABLE` and `TIMESHEET_FILLED_BY`, making two tables unnecessary and more difficult to maintain.

In fact, if both `ENTERED_BY` and `TIMESHEET_FOR` are required in pairs, using **option 1** makes far more sense because this is automatically enforced by the database and foreign keys.

Comment: I am SSS and I endorse this answer :)

Comment: It works, but only if both FK has Delete and Update Options to NO ACTION. If you put "Cascade", or other options, it will give you an error. I have the same situation on my SQL 2008 Server, where I have two tables, Currency and CurrencyHistory. Currency has IdCurrency as primary key, and the second table has IdCurrency and IdCurrencyRefference, wich has to be the same Id Column from Currency table. So, the delete or update I have to do it from code, programmatically. That's it :)

Answer (score 4):

Option 1 is a perfect solution. You may define foreign key constraint as following

1st foreign key constraint for Timesheet_For column

```
ALTER TABLE TIMESHEETTABLE 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_TimesheetTable_EmployeeTable
FOREIGN KEY (TIMESHEET_FOR)
REFERENCES EMPLOYEETABLE(EMPLOYEE_ID)
```

2nd foreign key constraint for Entered_By column

```
ALTER TABLE TIMESHEETTABLE 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_TimesheetTable_EmployeeTable_1
FOREIGN KEY (ENTERED_BY)
REFERENCES EMPLOYEETABLE(EMPLOYEE_ID)
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, there is no problem with that...you can use a primary key of one table  in other table as foreign key two times.

Comment: What is term for that method..?, I want to read more about that.

Comment: this is a common practice, I don't think there a special method or term for that. @Harvest1018

Answer (score 1):

Your query like :

```
SELECT t.EMPLOYEE_ID, a.NAME as TimeSheetFor, b.NAME as EnteredBy 
FROM timesheet t
JOIN employee a ON t.timesheet_for =a.employee_id
JOIN employee b ON t.entered_by = b.employee_id
```

Using this query you will get result as you want.